# fromNow displays different strings on different browsers

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I pass a date string `2015/05/14-02:55 pm` to moment.js constructor and i am using `fromNow` to convert it into a readable format. When i run this command on 16th May, chrome displays right output but mozilla says `a few seconds ago`.

**firefox console output:**

[image]

**chrome console output:**

[image]

Is this a problem with my mozilla time settings? I ran `Date()` on mozilla console. It correctly printed the date as:

```
"Sat May 16 2015 15:18:02 GMT+0530 (IST)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the `moment` from a String, and it is [not recommended](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because
>   there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what
>   works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings,
>   you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Just pass the format as the second parameter and it will show correctly on any browser:

```
moment('2015/05/14-02:55 pm', 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH:mm A').fromNow()
```